# kinect on ros indigo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i try to install openni-launch on indigo and raspberry pi B+.
i run this command: `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni-launch`
i receive this error although i am connecting to the internet:

> E: Unable to locate package
> ros-indigo-openni-launch

what can i do please ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234801/kinect-on-ros-indigo/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-05-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [easyspidy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26933/easyspidy/) on 2016-05-20**:
which version of kinect sensor you are using? kinect v1 (xbox 360) or kinect v2 (xbox one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`openni_kinect` is deprecated, you should use `freenect_stack`  instead from http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_stack

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-freenect-stack
```

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2016-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-05-20**:
the same error, if i install any ide it is ok but not package ROS

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-05-20**:
Try downloads the package lists before:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-05-20**:
yes i do this